# htaccess a dynamic URL

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I'm using Wordpress with a plugin and it's currently making urls like this: `http://www.example.com/?name=the-office`

I would like to redirect all similar urls to `http://www.example.com/name/the-office`

```
Current htaccess:

    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried a few things and nothing seemed to work, maybe I'm need to place the RewriteCond in the IfModule? Not sure, htaccess is foreign to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Redirecting `/?name=the-office` to `/name/the-office` won’t solve the problem that the “wrong URLs” are used in the first place. You also need to adjust Wordpress to deliver documents with the “right URLs” in them.

Comment: also check that in apache your mod_rewrite is enabled

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a workaround that is much easier to accomplish - simply login to your wordpress admin panel, go to settings, then permalinks and there you can select how your links will look like. Select the last option (Post name) to get only post names in the urls.